# SQL query not returning correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query with multiple joins for which `DOC_TYPE` column is coming NULL even if it has some values in it. The query is below

```
SELECT 
    a.mkey,
    c.type_desc DOC_TYPE,
    a.doc_no INWARD_NO,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.doc_date, 103) date,
    a.to_user,
    a.No_of_pages,
    Ref_No,
    c.type_desc DEPT_RECEIVED,
    c.type_desc EMP_RECEIVED,
    b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name NAME,
    b.email
FROM
    inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
LEFT JOIN 
    user_mst b ON a.to_user = b.mkey
LEFT JOIN 
    type_mst_a c ON a.doc_type = c.master_mkey
                 AND a.dept_received = c.Master_mkey
                 AND a.emp_received = c.Master_mkey
WHERE  
    a.to_user = '1279'
```

The `doc_type` value is `428` and whose desciption comes from

```
select type_desc 
from type_mst_a 
where master_mkey = 428
```

as `Drawing` but when I run the join query I get it as NULL. why ??

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Check your data, is last ON predicate satisfied?

Comment: @Serg: what are you telling, I didn't got u ?

Comment: I mean `a.doc_type = c.master_mkey and
a.dept_received = c.Master_mkey and
a.emp_received = c.Master_mkey` predicate, you said `a.doc_type` =428, what about `a.dept_received` and `a.emp_received` ?

Comment: you were used left join. so the records which does't exist in type_mst_a table will not show up

Comment: @Serg: they are also coming `NULL`.  Also `a.dept_received = 816`

Comment: @bmsqldev: so which join should I go for ?

Comment: i think an inner join makes sense in this scenario

Comment: @bmsqldev: no records with `inner` join

Comment: So Sql server've done exactly what you asked it to do. Your ON predicate is not true and you've got NULLs

Comment: @Serg: so what's the main thing I am missing here ?? any clue

Comment: I can only  suppose it. Probably you expressed your intention to Sql server in a wrong way. Please explain us what are you trying to do. Effectively  the last ON requires `a.doc_type =  a.dept_received = a.emp_received = c.Master_mkey` is it what you really need?

Comment: As @Serg said It would be an issue with your table data

Comment: @Serg: yes surely will explain you all the details.

Comment: @Serg: sorry, this is the new room some mistake happened their. connect to this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112138/room-for-n-k-and-serg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion current version is

```
SELECT
  a.mkey, c.type_desc DOC_TYPE, a.doc_no INWARD_NO, 
  convert(varchar, a.doc_date,103) date, a.to_user, a.No_of_pages, Ref_No, d.type_desc DEPT_RECEIVED, 
  b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name SENDER, b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name   NAME, b.email 
FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr a 
-- LEFT ?
JOIN user_mst b ON a.to_user = b.mkey 
JOIN type_mst_a c ON a.doc_type = c.master_mkey 
JOIN type_mst_a d ON a.dept_received = d.Master_mkey 
WHERE 
  a.to_user = '1279'
```

LEFT JOIN is needed if `inward_doc_tracking_hdr` rows with NULLs or having no matches still must be present in the  result.
Hope we are now on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are performing a left join, all of the conditions in the join clause need to be satisfied to return values from the joined table otherwise they will be null. I.e.

```
   a.doc_type = c.master_mkey AND
   a.dept_received = c.Master_mkey AND
   a.emp_received = c.Master_mkey
```

if you change your LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN, I bet you get no results at all right?

If you simply perform a select on both tables looking at your master_mkey = 428, you should see one of the fields (a.dept_received, a.emp_received) has a different value than 428 and this will be the reason you are getting a null.

Answer (score 0):

I think change `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` will solve your issue. (Since you are fetching doc_no from the Left table)

```
   SELECT a.mkey,
           c.type_desc                        DOC_TYPE,
           a.doc_no                           INWARD_NO,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.doc_date, 103)  date,
           a.to_user,
           a.No_of_pages,
           Ref_No,
           c.type_desc                         DEPT_RECEIVED,
           c.type_desc                         EMP_RECEIVED,
           b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name    NAME,
           b.email
    FROM   inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
    INNER JOIN user_mst b
      ON (a.to_user = b.mkey)
    INNER JOIN type_mst_a c
      ON (a.doc_type = c.master_mkey
         AND a.dept_received = c.Master_mkey
         AND a.emp_received  = c.Master_mkey)
    WHERE  a.to_user = '1279'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of Left join you have to use inner join in order to get records having doc_type. This query will help you :**

```
SELECT a.mkey,
       c.type_desc                      DOC_TYPE,
       a.doc_no                         INWARD_NO,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.doc_date, 103)date,
       a.to_user,
       a.No_of_pages,
       Ref_No,
       c.type_desc                      DEPT_RECEIVED,
       c.type_desc                      EMP_RECEIVED,
       b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name NAME,
       b.email
FROM   inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
       INNER JOIN user_mst b
              ON a.to_user = b.mkey
       INNER JOIN type_mst_a c
              ON a.doc_type = c.master_mkey
                 AND a.dept_received = c.Master_mkey
                 AND a.emp_received = c.Master_mkey
WHERE  a.to_user = '1279'
```